# URL of Website Changed by itself

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a problem with my client's website. It is from time to time changing its URLs by itself. E.g. we have there a website directly going to  /get-started and it for example was changed to /get-started-2.

The same problem occurred in our language version of the website and instead of /users - it changes to the /users-3.

Do you have any idea why it is constantly changing? Because then it is showing coverage issues in GSC as a result.

Thanks a lot for helping and giving advice in advance.

Comment: It shouldn't do that. I'd guess something's going wrong updating the page, either an automated process or human error. Have you, or anyone else on your site, changed the page? Do you have automated processes for updating or republishing pages?

Comment: Yes, we do have on a website automated processes for updating  plugins but not for republishing netheir updating pages. It is not certainly a human error since it is showing on different sites. Where elsewhere could be the error made?

Comment: May it be caused by some of the plugins?